# IErrorInfo.GetSource failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-search

I am using below statement to query the windows search and getting the above error and following error `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)` .

```
  var query = "SELECT System.ItemName FROM servername.SystemIndex " +
               "WHERE SCOPE='file://servername/temp/DanB/Newsletter' 
                  and contains('" +   txtSearch.Text + "')";
```

*(I haven't mention the servername above, but I am using the correct server name)*

I did search about this error and seems it may occur due to usage of reserved words and symbols. I have gone through [Access 2007 reserved words and symbols](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx#top), and seems the this statement is fine.

Even though, I suspect ***temp*** may causing any trouble so I tried ***[temp]*** but its same result.

Also I check the value coming from the text box as well.

So I tried coping the file to local drive and it worked.

```
 var query =  "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
              "WHERE SCOPE='file:C:/Users/temp/DanB/Newsletter' 
                 and contains('" + txtSearch.Text + "')";
```

I have gone thought the [FROM Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding the windows search and the syntax (querying network drive) looks fine to me.

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Assuming Access has it, you should really be using a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)... especially if this is taking user input.

Comment: @JeffBridgman:I am testing it with diffrerent keywords, that why I am using a textbox for the moment. But the real issue is the abouve error!!

Comment: Click the windows key and the R key (or bring up the run dialog box)  enter in \\servername\temp\DanB\Newsletter  does it open a folder? The error is either a permission error or the folder does not exist.  the usual context is \\servername\sharename

Comment: @Sorceri: I tried using `run` and it works fine (it brings up the location with no issues)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Can you check permissions?  When you go to the file location yourself, the server is checking your permissions.  When you run the code the code will be executed under a different, asp.net login that may not have permissions on the server.  Check what login is being used, and that logins permissiosn on the server.

Comment: @Vulcronos: Windows authentication been used, server permissions are fine as well!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Can you conect to any file or filepath on the server using c#?  We should check if the issue is with the server or just this folder.

Comment: What kind of OS the remote machine? Are you sure that Windows Search is installed on the remote box?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: Yes windows search is there with indexing enabled

Comment: @Vulcronos: Yes, I tried opening same file using the application. It works fine

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I have double checked your syntax and everything else I can find but everything looks good.  Unless you can give us more details I don't know anything else to do to help.  I would just test different scenarios on your end.  Can you search other computers?  Other folders on that server?

Answer (score 0):

We have remove the indexing from the server and re-set it up. Which workd fine now